# Show pending migrations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Is there a rake task that shows the pending migrations in a rails app?

Answer (score 313):

`rake db:migrate:status` (Rails 3 to 5) or `rails db:migrate:status` (Rails 5+) will accomplish this. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e3e117dbe58fd4fedbb78a3d8e398ab0e415634).

`up` means the migration has been run. `down` means the migration has not been run.

Comment: I'm getting `Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:status'` on rails 3.2.8

Comment: @PeterEhrlich: Does it not show up in `rake -T` but the other ones do?

Comment: bundle exec rake db:migrate:status

Comment: How do you read the output of this command? If the status of a row is "down", does that mean it's a pending migration?

Comment: `up` means the migration has been run.  `down` means the migration has not been run.

Comment: check out this gist for more rake tasks not in `rake -T` @jrdioko https://gist.github.com/amejiarosario/2950888

Answer (score 45):

There is `rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations` (at least in Rails 2.3.3, not sure when it was introduced). The description says 'Raises an error if there are pending migrations'. This seems to be used more as a prerequisite for other tasks, but I'm guessing you could use it for your purposes.

EDIT: Here is an example of the output after having just generated and not run a 'test' migration

```
rails_project theIV$ rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations
(in /Users/theIV/Sites/rails_project/)
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20090828200602 Test
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
```

Comment: I love adding this to orchestrate dependencies between rails containers

Comment: Still there in Rails 4.1.16

Comment: Works in rails 5.1.3 as well

Answer (score 20):

This command will list all migrations with their status (`UP` or `DOWN`)

**Rails 3 and 4**

```bash
rake db:migrate:status
```

**Rails 5 and above**

```bash
rake db:migrate:status

# Or

rails db:migrate:status
```

This will return something like

```
database: blog_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20210131124730  Create articles
  down    20210131124801  Create users
```

Answer (score 16):

`rake db:version` will accomplish this on Rails 2.

Comment: Also valid in rails 3.2.18

Answer (score 14):

This works for rails 5.2

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see how much migration is done or pending you can see using below command.

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

More on this link: [Rails  Active Record Migration](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you need a bash one-liner to determine whether to run a migration or not (e.g., only migrate in a [Heroku release phase command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) when there is a pending migration), this works:

```
(rails db:migrate:status | grep "^\s*down") && rails db:migrate || echo "No pending migrations found."
```

Answer (score 2):

Try rake -h (help) and have a look at rake -n (= rake --dry-run).  So probably something like rake -n db:migrate should get you what you want.

Comment: That won't work. It just prints:     ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute (dry run) environment
    ** Execute (dry run) db:migrate

Answer (score 2):

Might not quite be what OP is asking for, but if you just need to quickly check if any migrations are pending for use in a rake task, without resorting to

rake db:migrate:status | grep down (might not work if you're on Windows)

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! (raises ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError that you need to rescue)

you can use needs_migration? method: 
https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Migrator/needs_migration%3F/class

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?` in Rails 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Following command to check migration status:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

OR

when you run your server, it will display a message to run your pending migration first.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.open.pending_migrations
```

Return:

```
#<struct ActiveRecord::MigrationProxy name="AddColumnHabilitaHrSobreavisoToTbhorarios", version=20231013134900, filename="/home/rodrigo/projects/engines/gpweb_frequencia/db/migrate/20231013134900_add_column_habilita_hr_sobreaviso_to_tbhorarios.rb", scope="">
```

Comment: The code is fairly clear but it could use some explanation.