# How can I tell what changes 'rake db:migrate' will apply before applying them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

The command `rake db:migrate` will apply all relevant new migrations to a database and will list in the output the migrations that were applied.

I'd like to know in advance what migrations will be applied so as to note down a list of the changes that are expected in a production environment.

Is there an option I can use in conjunction to `rake db:migrate` that will show me what changes will be applied without actually applying them?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Does `rake db:migrate:status` (rails 3+ only) fit the bill?

Comment: Indeed this does! I neglected to mention I was pre-3.x, but I'll be 3.x soon. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess here's the answer: [Show pending migrations in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349047/show-pending-migrations-in-rails) .

If you are deploying with capistarno, you could add a task similar to this: http://gem-session.com/2010/08/warn-of-pending-migrations-when-deploying-with-capistrano .